# Error in loadNamespace Rstudio

Tags: r, package

I am having real trouble understanding what my problem is installing ggplot package in Rstudio. I have tried a number of the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758129/error-in-loadnamespacename-there-is-no-package-called-rcpp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170399/changing-r-default-library-path-using-libpaths-in-rprofile-site-fails-to-work) but I still can't fix the problem.

I understand that I have a library directory on my Windows machine which can be found using:

`.libPaths()` which returns
`[1] "C:/Users/Bo Bo/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library"`

I'm not sure what is stored in this directory using .Library but it looks to be pointing to the wrong directory, 3.2.3 and 32~1.3???:

`[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/library"`

Upon installing ggplot2

`install.packages("ggplot2")` returns:

`Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Bo Bo/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/ggplot2_2.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2001769 bytes (1.9 MB)
downloaded 1.9 MB`

`package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`

`The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Bo Bo\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4QKdwV\downloaded_packages`

So is it dumping the package in a temp directory because the 'lib' is unspecified? If so how do I specify the 'lib' and which library needs to change.

By the way I followed @Paweł Rumian post in link 2 above meaning I have a new User variable called R_LIBS_USER pointing to C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library

Can anyone make a suggestion as to how I can resolve this conflict and move on with my life :)

Comment: I see no conflict. R always dumps a copy in a temp directory (which then gets erased later. This looks as though it should have succeeded. What happens when you type `library(ggplot2)`?

Comment: When running library(ggplot2) I got `Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’` So I tried installing via install.packages("ggplot2") and I received a prompt saying: Warning in install.packages :'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library"' is not writable -> "Would you like to use a personal library instead": `Warning in install.packages :
  cannot create dir 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\library\file911c54e945eb', reason 'Permission denied'
Error in install.packages : unable to create temporary directory ‘C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\library\file911c54e945eb’`

Comment: Do I need to modify the permissions on R-3.2.3/library to read/write?? I read somewhere else on SO that it could be related to antivirus, any ideas??

Comment: You do have a path entry in `.libPaths()` to a personal library which I'm guessing would have the correct permissions if it exists, which I would have expected to be used, but you might try specifying it (as the error message suggests) rather than letting the defaults remain in effect.

Comment: I reinstalled R and Rstudio this afternoon and I am still having the same issues. I checked the permissions on C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library and it was set to read only. I unselected read only and tried running my code again. Again I received the same warning: 'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library"' is not writable. I checked the path properties again and it was reset to read only!!!

Comment: I've checked a number of folder permissions on my laptop and all of them have 'read only' permissions. I am running Win 10 and from doing a quick search there's known issues with Win 10 and read only permissions. Off to dig into this mess....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up re-installing windows after hours of trying to modify/fix the permissions issue I was having with all folders on the local disk.

Since re-installing I have installed Rstudio as per before and I am back in business, no messing around with library locations, just plain vanilla for me please...