# Install r libraries

Tags: r

I have installed an R project on a network. It automatically installs the library in the `C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\downloaded_packages`, however, I would like to install the library to lets say `Q:\Apps\R-Project\Libraries`.

I managed to install the library to the Q network using the following command:

```
install.packages("dplyr", lib="Q:\Apps\R-Project\Libraries", dependencies=T)
```

When I load the library it says that it cannot find the `Rccp`.

Any help how to solve that issue?

Comment: Make sure is in your `.libPath()`. You can add it with `.libPath() <- c(.libPath(), "Q:\Apps\R-Project\Libraries")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told `R` to install the package in a certain location, namely `Q:\Apps\R-Project\Libraries`.

When you tell `R` to use a certain package, `R` will not search your entire computer whether that package exists. Usually, the packages are being saved in a standard location that `R` knows and where `R` will also search for it, once you tell it to use that package. You can view these locations with `.libPaths()`.

If `Q:\Apps\R-Project\Libraries` is not a location that you have saved in `.libPaths()`, you have two options:

```
# 1) Add it to `.libPaths()` like this: 
.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "Q:\Apps\R-Project\Libraries") )

# 2) Tell `R` explicitly where to look while loading the package:     
library(packagename, lib.loc = "Q:\Apps\R-Project\Libraries")
```

I recommend using option 1

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I try the first approach and when I load the library it says: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’

Comment: While you are trying to load `dplyr`?

Comment: yes. I use you know normal install.packages("dplyr", dependencies=T). Thank you again for your quick response :)

Comment: That can happen. `Rcpp` is being loaded automatically when you load `dplyr`. Somehow `Rcpp` and `dplyr` need to be installed in the same location, in order for them to nicely work together and fullfill their dependencies. Check this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/16759366/6256482