# devtools::document() yields In loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called ‘Rcpp,’

Tags: r, rcpp

Dont know how to better phrase this.

Each time I source a Rcpp file or even compile the whole package I get the warning message:

```
Warning message:
In loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp,’
```

I previously assumed it was related to Rstudio so ignored it and the code still ran fine. I decided to install new Rstudi and still get the same warning.

Note that the warning claims there is no Rcpp, yet there is:

```
Rcpp::getRcppVersion()
[1] ‘1.0.11’
```

I am not quite sure howto handle the warning. Any help willbe appreciated.

NB: The code still loads and works fine. Just that the warning is annoying-- A warning indicates something is not right somewhere.

Comment: Maybe one of these answers could be helpful: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758129/error-in-loadnamespacename-there-is-no-package-called-rcpp>

Comment: If you have the `sessioninfo` package installed, please post the output from `sessioninfo::session_info()`, as it provides some context that basic version reporting may not.

Comment: @r2evans The output from `session_info()` is too large. Probably just the sestting values or?

Comment: I was hoping to verify that `Rcpp` was not installed in a shortcut fashion such as `devtools`/`remotes`, that's mostly it. It's a stretch, likely not the culprit. Is this reproducible in a fresh R instance? Is this a single-file script (can you make the question reproducible) or is there a repo/branch that is triggering the issue?

Comment: @TarJae the solution provided talks of `RInside` package. I do not have that installed. I believe i do notneed it. The warning started once I run `devtools::document()` and its now persistent

Comment: @r2evans The issue is persistent whether I restart Rstudio or not. I ended up installing the latest Rstudio. Also its a multiple-file script. Although even when I just Run the default RCPP new file `timesTwo(42)`, I still get the warning. Everything was working fine then from nowhere it just appeared.

Comment: Not sure, I've not run into that warning before. Are you loading any packages via `load_all` or similar? Is there any forking/`future`-like something going on? Have you tried in R outside of RStudio, just to rule out that as a contributing factor?

Comment: @Onyambu I usually recommend to simplify.  Create the simplest possible package (possibly via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`, run `R CMD build` and `R CMD INSTALL` on it and verify that this (documented) approach.  The swap in the approach we do not use and see if you can get it to work. I do not use `devtools`, I find these tools opaque as they hide what they do and where errors occur but if _you_ what to use them you surely can.  I just cannot help you with errors that are shown to be `Rcpp` errors. Such as this one,

Comment: @Onyambu Morevover, your question is not reproducible as you show no code. `devtools` goes off and tests in a fresh environment, so if `Rcpp` is lacking _in that fresh environment_ then maye your `DESCRIPTION` file does not list `Rcpp` correctly?  Again, I would start from something simpler that works and go from there.

Comment: @r2evans not yet tried that. Just installed a new R, Once I ran the `devtools::document()` the first time, everything worked out fine. Then the moment I reran it, The issue popped up again

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks. Will definitely take that into consideration. It seems the warning relates to running the code multiple times. Will have to figure this out

Comment: One thing that seems inoccuous, but ... it doesn't say that it cannot find `'Rcpp'`, it says that it cannot find `'Rcpp,'` (with a comma). Perhaps is there a typo somewhere in your code? Reproducible with `loadNamespace("Rcpp,")` which gives the same warning (and the `call.=` referenced there looks like https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/base/R/namespace.R#L525)

Comment: @r2evans OH GRACIOUS!!! That was the issue. Did a quick grep on the directory. There was an importFrom tag with a comma immediately after Rcpp. Wow... Thanks alot mate

Comment: @r2evans Should give it to you. Just post that

Comment: It's funny (not always "ha ha") how small punctuation and/or diacritic marks can escape our immediate scan of something. I just read an article how a small little access under the `k` of `keepass.info` leads to a website that has nothing to do with KeePass ([ref](https://arstechnica.com/security/2023/10/google-hosted-malvertising-leads-to-fake-keepass-site-that-looks-genuine/)). Easy to miss things like that!

Comment: (`s/access/accent/`, sigh)

Comment: @Onyambu, the next trick is to find out why you got the warning not on the first but the second (and subsequent?) loading of the package ...

Comment: @r2evans I really cant tell why. But it would be something if i end up getting this error again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front: there's a comma somewhere where referencing `Rcpp`.

If this were simply a matter of the package not available, we would see a clear single-quoted package name, instead there's punctuation inside of the quotes (intentionally lower-case here):

```r
loadNamespace("rcpp")
# Error in loadNamespace("rcpp") : there is no package called ‘rcpp’
loadNamespace("rcpp,")
# Error in loadNamespace("rcpp,") : there is no package called ‘rcpp,’
```

It's easy to miss things like that in our scan, I suspect our eyes want to see `'rcpp',` instead.

Comment: Well spotted indeed!

Comment: @Onyambu You cannot sort / rearrange comments, They remain chronological.  In any event the question should like be delete as it "was caused by a typo" which is indeed one of the categories.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel that was me (not Onyambu) that suggested it, but ... I don't disagree, though I think "closed" versus "deleted" is perhaps more appropriate, let the system deal with culling it out later. (Having said that ... I do think that while this is a typo, it just _might_ help somebody to recognize it in their own warnings/errors ... meh)

Comment: Yes, sorry, meant closed.  Delete or not may happen once closed, no strong feelings.  We have over 3000 posts now, it is hard enough to search.  These things are often XY problems.  (And yes my first comment to your answer also congratulates you on spotting this.)